# IntelliJ: Annotate button doesn't display username from git

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Facing a very weird issue in IntelliJ since last few days. I've configured git with IntelliJ. By clicking on Annotate, I could easily see name of person who wrote the code but since last few days it is not working for **me**. PFB required images.

**Annotate:**
[image: While clicking on Annotate]

**While it was working:**
[image: Working scenario]

**Present situation:**
(Please note blank space instead of name, Ambani)
[image: Note blank space]

Please let me know if further inputs required

**Version:** 2016.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The light green vertical shade(on the right of your debug points) that you see is the uncommitted code. Hence intelliJ is unable to detect any annotations on that. You can check that by by confirming that

```
git status
```

would list out the file that you've shared.

So once those changes are committed

```
git commit -am "sample"
```

just try to hide and reopen annotations, that portion of code would also be annotated.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response, previously it used to annotate developer name before pushing the code. :|

Comment: @PratikAmbani Well I have been using the same feature for a while now. I haven't seen that happen **without commiting** and the images shared by you are also clear in terms of the difference between the two. :)

Comment: @PratikAmbani Sure, if it helps do accept the answer and let me know ;)

Comment: Take a bow mate, my bad. Been using this IDE since a year and did such idiotic blunder :D Thanks for the help. GB